# Could not open a connection to the database

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to install a CMS throught the MS Web Platform Installer. During the installation process, it gives me an error saying "Could not open a connection to the database. This could be network or instance specific error."
Here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUroV.jpg of the error.

In Configuration Manager, Named Pipes, TCP/IP and Shared memory are enabled. I entered the server name as .\sqlexpress.

Comment: We're named pipes/TCP/IP already enabled on the instance when it started up? Configuration Manager shows you what the current configured values are, not necessarily the running values. If you're unsure, restart the SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your `Services` to make sure that the `SQL Express` service instance is running.

Answer (score 0):

Well CakePhp is a PHP framework , and by default uses MySql .

Please make sure that mysql is intsalled and running as a service.

Also make sure no other process is listening on port # 3306 as that is by default the port of mysql

Comment: :P The database is MSSQL but only named as cakephp :P